# Jenkins Job fails in Mac OS catalina

Tags: macos

I have installed Jenkins in Mac OS and trying to run a sample maven project but everytime build fails /bin/sh: /Users/aartiashok/Desktop/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn: Operation not permitted

I have given full disk access to terminal and bash.

Please assist

Comment: Is this related to Emacs in any way? If not, you have a better chance to get an answer if you post the question in another forum.

Comment: looks like a OS-level permissions trouble more than an emacs problem as @Lindydancer said.

Comment: What are the access rights on that file?

Comment: How is your Jenkins been installed ?? As a WAR deployed in an application server - as a docker image - started a WAR with java -jar jenkins.war ??